# Find and offset to copy value to the end of 2nd worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel files. 
I am trying to do the following:

1. Search for a value in Sheet one.
2. When item is found use offset to pick up the adjacent value i.e. 4 columns to the left (same row)
3. Add the value (in step 2) to sheet two at the end of Row D

Struggling with the third step.
I get method or data member not found.

```
Sub findOne()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("one") ' ref to sheet one
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("two") ' ref to sheet two

Dim rng As Range

With ws1

    ' use find on range H
    Set rng = Range("H1:H200").Find(What:="busaoc", LookAt:=xlPart)

    '- doesn't like this   
    ws2.Range("D2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = ws1.rng(.Offset(0, -4))

End With

end Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not using your `With` block, but I removed it here since it doesn't seem necessary *if* this is your complete code. This has also been amended to not crash on the chance your value is actually not found.

```
Sub findOne()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("one")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("two")
Dim rng As Range, LR As Long

Set rng = ws1.Range("H1:H200").Find(What:="busaoc", LookAt:=xlPart)

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Value not found"
Else
    LR = ws2.Range("D" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    ws2.Range("D" & LR).Value = rng.Offset(0, -4).Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean @JohnyL